# Почему исчез раздел <<Исследования>>?

Tags: обсуждение

Создал новый профиль в сообществе <<Русский язык>> под тем же ником, что и старый. Доступ к старому профилю и своим ответам получил. Но в старом профиле отсутствуют три моих исследования — остался только ответ по одному из исследований. Я смотрю, что в обновлённом сайте вообще отсутствует раздел <<Исследования>>. А у меня практически уже почти наготове ещё несколько исследований. Почему удалён раздел <<Исследования>>?! Кто поддержит меня за восстановление раздела <<Исследования>>?

**Обновление** для *@ Nicolas Chabanovsky* от 08.05.20015 г.

Моих исследований было три. Перечисляю:

1. Вариации букв Ц и Ч .
2. Вариации СТ/ШТ — Щ .
3. Что такое ПРОЩЕЛЫГА? Исправляем Вл. Даля.

По 1-му исследованию был вопрос от @Innak, на который я давал ответ. Эта публикация сохранилась. Можете посмотреть дискуссионные материалы по ссылке  [Вариация букв Ц и Ч](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/38483/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2-%D0%A6-%D0%B8-%D0%A7/38644#38644). Были и исследования других участников, но я отвечаю только за свои.

Answer (score 3):

Раздел "Исследования" не существует на новом форуме. Все исследования были преобразованы в вопросы без ответа.

Сеть форумов Stack Exchange намного больше, чем была Сеть Знаний (в Stack Exchange входит порядка 140 сообществ). С ходу, вернуть "исследования", к сожалению, не получится, так как любые изменения затронут все сайты сети.

Comment: Я просмотрел все "ВОПРОСЫ БЕЗ ОТВЕТА" , но не обнаружил там своих (равно , как и других) ИССЛЕДОВАНИЙ . Может я не там смотрел ? В новой редакции сайта всё стало очень запутанно . Помогите разобраться : где искать ранее опубликованные ИССЛЕДОВАНИЯ ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, нет ли у вас возможности, привести список заголовков исследований, которые, как вам кажется, не были импортированы?

Comment: @ Nicolas Chabanovsky. Смотрите ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ в моем вопросе .